# jquery autcomplete returning source array

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jquery's ajax function to fetch data from an external php file. The data that is returned from the php file will be used for the autocomplete function. But, instead of the autocomplete function suggesting each particular value from the array in the php file, it returns ALL of them. My jquery looks like this.

```
jQuery('input[name=past_team]:radio').click(function(){
            $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#year').fadeIn('slow');

            var year = $('#year').val();

            $('#year').change(function () {
                $('#shadow').val('');

                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "links.php",  
                    data: ({
                        year: year,
                        type: "past_team"
                    }),
                    success: function(data)      
                    {
                        var data = [data];

                        $("#shadow").autocomplete({ 
                            source: data
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The link.php file looks like this:

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once("functions.php");
connect();

$type = $_POST['type'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

if($type == "past_team")
{
    $funk   =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM past_season_team_articles WHERE year = '".$year."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count  =   mysql_num_rows($funk);
    $i      =   0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($funk))
    {
        $name[$i]   =   $row['team'];

        $i++;
    }

    $data = "";

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        if($i != ($count-1))
        {
            $data .= '"'.$name[$i].'", ';
        } else
        {
            $data .= '"'.$name[$i].'"';
        }
    }

    echo $data;
}
?>
```

The autocomplete works. But, it's just that when I begin to enter something in the input field, the suggestion that are loaded is the entire array. I'll get "Chicago Cubs", "Boston Red Sox", "Atlanta Braves", .....

Comment: I do believe you should return a jSON format for the autocomplete and not strings separated by comma. Am I right?

Comment: Your query in links.php selects records when the year matches. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, when it matches the year.

Comment: Ok. Please check the query results, if the query result is "Chicago Cubs", "Boston Red Sox", "Atlanta Braves", then the result is correct

Comment: you can do one thing that you echo your content in html format by using **<br />** or **div, ul li** tags instead of contaminate strings.

Comment: The query result is fine. It's in the correct json format too. I still have no idea what's up

Comment: what output do you expect from the json data?

Comment: A JSON array. What's being echoes out in the php is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use i.e. Json to render your output in the php script.
ATM it's not parsed by javascript only concaternated with "," to a single array element. I do not think that's what you want. Also pay attention to the required datastructure of data.

For a working example (on the Client Side see the Remote JSONP example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp )